# Can the qsort() function be used with a function template as the comparator?

Tags: c++, templates, qsort

I am trying to create a function template that receives an array as input and sorts it. In order to sort it, I thought I could use the `qsort()` function that is included in the header file `cstdlib` of the C++ standard library. The `qsort()` function requires a comparator function to be passed as an argument, which in this case needs to be a function template as well.

Unfortunately I simply cannot get it to work. The program compiles successfully if the comparator function is not a function template, but if it is, I get an error that says

`no matches converting function ‘compare2’ to type ‘__compar_fn_t {aka int (*)(const void*, const void*)}’`

To give you an idea of what I am talking about, here is an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int compare2(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(const int*) pa;
    int b = *(const int*) pb;
    if (a > b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a < b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <typename type>
void mySort(type* ptr, unsigned int n) //n represents size of array pointed to by ptr
{
    qsort(ptr, n, sizeof(ptr[0]), compare2);
    return;
}
```

The above code compiles without any problems, despite the fact that it wouldn't work in practice if an array containing anything other than integers was passed to the `mySort()` function.

Whereas the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template <typename type>
int compare2(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    type a = *(const type*) pa;
    type b = *(const type*) pb;
    if (a > b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a < b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <typename type>
void mySort(type* ptr, unsigned int n) //n represents size of array pointed to by ptr
{
    qsort(ptr, n, sizeof(ptr[0]), compare2);
    return;
}
```

fails to compile with the error that I previously mentioned.

I know that I can easily achieve my goal using other methods (such as using a sorting algorithm inside the `mySort()` function in the given example), however I really want to get to the bottom of this. Why does `qsort()` not work with a function template as comparator? Is it due to a mistake I've made or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Function template is not a function. You have to instantiate it. Try `compare2<type>`.

Comment: @Evg I think this actually works! Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `std::sort`? `std::sort(ptr, ptr + n);` much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compare2` is a template, not a function. To get a function, a compiler has to instantiate a template. To do that, it should know the template parameters. Typically, they can be deduced from function parameters. In the present case, no deduction is possible, so you have to be explicit by adding `<type>` to the template name:

```
qsort(ptr, n, sizeof(ptr[0]), compare2<type>);
```